# Что значит "Построить синтаксический анализатор для..."?

Tags: python, синтаксический-анализ

В общем недавно на фрилансе наткнулся на такой вот вид задач:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Естественно возникли вопросы. Заказчик написал: **"Решить программу, файл с заданием прикреплен. Язык программирования любой."**

Что он имел в виду? Я с такими задачами сталкиваюсь впервые и могу только догадываться про что идёт речь. Достаточно ли здесь просто определить классы для каждой переменной как тут, или нет?

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight):
        self.topLeft = topLeft
        self.topRight = topRight
        self.bottomLeft = bottomLeft
        self.bottomRight = bottomRight

class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Trapezoid(Rectangle):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #test
    point1 = Vertex(-1, 1)
    point2 = Vertex(1, 1)
    point3 = Vertex(-1, -1)
    point4 = Vertex(1, -1)
    rect = Rectangle(point1, point2, point3, point4)
```

Comment: Нет, не достаточно. Надо написать по заданной на скриншоте грамматике [синтаксический анализатор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), который будет разбирать текстовую строку (соответствующую грамматике) и формировать в памяти список геометрических фигур уже с этими классами, которые вы описали.

Comment: В грамматике кстати есть проблема: нет терминальных символов, которые позволяют отличить прямоугольник от трапеции.

Comment: При создании объекта нужно проверять углы - если 90 градусов, то создавать прямоугольник, если нет - то трапецию. А в остальном классы одинаковые.

Comment: Зачем брать задачу к реализации, если даже не понимаете о чём идёт речь? Вам надо читать теорию компиляторов и BNF  https://habr.com/ru/post/133780/

Comment: Понял, спасибо всем большое. Задачу на реализацию я не брал, просто стало интересно, что заказчик имел ввиду, столкнулся с таким впервые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, недостаточно. Синтаксический анализатор должен разобрать строку и создать объекты классов, которые вы написали. Т.е. входные данные строка - `{{{1.0} {0.0}} {{1.0} {1.0}} {{0.0} {1.0}} {{0.0} {0.0}}}`. В результате в программе создать объект класса `Rectangle`, содержащий 4 объекта класса `Vertex`, в свою очередь содержащих 2 объекта класса `число с точкой`, в свою очередь содержащих 2 объекта класса `целое без знака`.
Причем при создании объекта нужно проверять углы - если 90 градусов, то создавать прямоугольник, если нет - то трапецию. А в остальном классы прямоугольника и трапеции одинаковые.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за разъяснение! Очень благодарен